# Div position changes when it shouldnt

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const grouped = Object.groupBy(takvim, date =>date.tarih.substring(0,7))
const calendarContainer = document.getElementById('calendarContainer');
  for (const date in grouped) {
    const dateWrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');
    dateWrapperDiv.className = 'date-wrapper';
    const dateDiv = document.createElement('div');
    dateDiv.className = 'date';
    dateDiv.id = `date-${date}`;
    dateDiv.textContent = `Tarih: ${date}`;
    dateWrapperDiv.appendChild(dateDiv);

    grouped[date].forEach(event => {
      const eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
      eventDiv.className = 'event';
      eventDiv.textContent = `- ${event.ad} (${event.miles} ${event.tarih.substring(8,10)})`;
      dateWrapperDiv.appendChild(eventDiv);
    });
    calendarContainer.appendChild(dateWrapperDiv);

    const emptyLine = document.createElement('div');
    emptyLine.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    calendarContainer.appendChild(emptyLine);
  }
const prevButton = document.createElement('button');
prevButton.textContent = 'Önceki';
const nextButton = document.createElement('button');
nextButton.textContent = 'Sonraki';

calendarContainer.parentNode.insertBefore(prevButton, calendarContainer);
calendarContainer.parentNode.insertBefore(nextButton, calendarContainer);

let currentDate = null;

function hideAllDates() {
  const dateWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.date-wrapper');
  for (const dateWrapper of dateWrappers) {
    dateWrapper.style.display = 'none';
    dateWrapper.style.position = 'static';
  }
}
hideAllDates();

showDate(Object.keys(grouped)[0]);
function showDate(date) {
  const dateDiv = document.getElementById(`date-${date}`); 
  dateDiv.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
  dateDiv.parentNode.style.zIndex = '0';
  currentDate = date;
}


prevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const dates = Object.keys(grouped);
  const index = dates.indexOf(currentDate);
  if (index > 0) {
    hideAllDates();
    showDate(dates[index - 1]);
  }
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const dates = Object.keys(grouped);
  const index = dates.indexOf(currentDate);
  if (index < dates.length - 1) {
    hideAllDates();
    showDate(dates[index + 1]);
  }
});

  function showModal() {
    const modal = document.getElementById('customModal');
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  }

  function closeModal() {
    const modal = document.getElementById('customModal');
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
  const dateWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.date-wrapper');
  for (const dateWrapper of dateWrappers) {
    dateWrapper.style.position = 'static';
  }
```

```css
 #calendarContainer {
  }
  
  .date-wrapper { 
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="calendarContainer" class="calendar"></div>
```

```js
const grouped = Object.groupBy(takvim, date => date.tarih.substring(0, 7))
const calendarContainer = document.getElementById('calendarContainer');
for (const date in grouped) {
  const dateWrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');
  dateWrapperDiv.className = 'date-wrapper';
  const dateDiv = document.createElement('div');
  dateDiv.className = 'date';
  dateDiv.id = `date-${date}`;
  dateDiv.textContent = `Date: ${date}`;
  dateWrapperDiv.appendChild(dateDiv);

  grouped[date].forEach(event => {
    const eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
    eventDiv.className = 'event';
    eventDiv.textContent = `- ${event.ad} (${event.miles} ${event.tarih.substring(8,10)})`;
    dateWrapperDiv.appendChild(eventDiv);
  });
  calendarContainer.appendChild(dateWrapperDiv);

  const emptyLine = document.createElement('div');
  emptyLine.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  calendarContainer.appendChild(emptyLine);
}
const prevButton = document.createElement('button');
prevButton.textContent = 'Back';
const nextButton = document.createElement('button');
nextButton.textContent = 'Forward';

calendarContainer.parentNode.insertBefore(prevButton, calendarContainer);
calendarContainer.parentNode.insertBefore(nextButton, calendarContainer);

let currentDate = null;

function hideAllDates() {
  const dateWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.date-wrapper');
  for (const dateWrapper of dateWrappers) {
    dateWrapper.style.display = 'none';
    dateWrapper.style.position = 'static';
  }
}
hideAllDates();

showDate(Object.keys(grouped)[0]);

function showDate(date) {
  const dateDiv = document.getElementById(`date-${date}`);
  dateDiv.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
  dateDiv.parentNode.style.zIndex = '0';
  currentDate = date;
}


prevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const dates = Object.keys(grouped);
  const index = dates.indexOf(currentDate);
  if (index > 0) {
    hideAllDates();
    showDate(dates[index - 1]);
  }
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const dates = Object.keys(grouped);
  const index = dates.indexOf(currentDate);
  if (index < dates.length - 1) {
    hideAllDates();
    showDate(dates[index + 1]);
  }
});
```

```css
#calendarContainer {}

.date-wrapper {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendarContainer" class="calendar"></div>
```

when i go forward or backward with buttons my dateWrapper div's position changes it goes down or goes up depending on the button how can i change it to stay still all the time? can it be because of the appendChild lines? i am relatively to javascript, i tried all the things i can do but it didn't work

Comment: You should add the CSS that you have as that is what will govern the elements positions and sizes. Also add the HTML that is associated with this behaviour

Comment: edited check now

Comment: I've created a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you. Please update the code so there are no more errors. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: im sorry i didnt understand @Reyno